# Java - How to fix size of html tags to their contents in JTextPane?

Tags: java, html, css, swing, jtextpane

I have a `JTextPane`, with html content :

```
    Pane = new JTextPane();
    Pane.setEditable(false);
    Pane.setContentType("text/html");
    Pane.setEditorKit(kit);
    Pane.setText("<html><body><div id='content'></div></body></html>");
    doc = (HTMLDocument) Pane.getStyledDocument();
    content = doc.getElement("content");
```

I add my html element in runtime with :

```
doc.insertBeforeEnd(content, "<p class = 'text'>"+text+"</p>"); // text is input from user
```

here is CSS that I use :

```
    styleSheet = doc.getStyleSheet();
    styleSheet.addRule("body{background-color:#FFFFFF;}");
    styleSheet.addRule("#content {margin: 0% 10%; width : 80%; }");
    styleSheet.addRule("img {height : 10px; width : 10px;  }");
    styleSheet.addRule(".text{display: inline-block;background-color:#E2EAF3;margin : 2px;padding : 1px 10px;; border-radius: 4px;border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: #D5D3CD;text-align: right;clear: both;float: right;}");
```

I know that the float,clear,... property not rendered yet. ([Class CSS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/CSS.html))

because of limited support of CSS property, all the `<p>` elements that I insert have the same length, but I want to set max size for the width, so if the `text` size is longer it wraps, and if it is shorter then the background fixed to its content.

Untitled1 in img.rar is the screenshot.

EDIT1:

I add `Pane` to the `JPanel` with `BorderLayout`.

```
panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
```

EDIT2:

I change my html code for inserting text to following :

```
doc.insertBeforeEnd(content, "<table class = 'text'><tr><td>"+text+"</td></tr></table>");
```

now it fix to content (Untitled2 in img.rar) but I want to set max width, and put tables in center of html.

screenshot's pictures

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 part of the problem.

The first one how to define the width property and how to get it from model Element. Try to investigate the HTMLDocument tree Elements and try to get the 400.

The second part is relatively easier. If you can read the width setting from the Element (either from attributes or from style) you can override javax.swing.text.html.ParagraphView in the HTMLEditorKit's ViewFactory and return 400 (the width prom property/style/attribte) for getPreferredSpan/getMinumumSpan/getMaximumSpan and X_AXIS

Comment: I change my html code (I edit my post), so now my problem is to set max width..., could you plz help me with that!